# SQL Server : add a new column using union

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, union

I have 2 tables which have 2 columns in common and 1 column is different in both table

Table A

[image]

Table B

[image]

I need to create a common table having the values as follows

Expected Output

[image]

I tried using join on Memid and Meas but it duplicates as the 2 field do not create unique set as shown in figure

I tried union but then I get a resultset like this

[image]

Output for Inner join with distinct condition

[image]

How do I go about achieving the desired result set?

Note: Just a note coincidentally in this case the 2 columns seems to have similar values but they can be different.

Basically I need to create this one table with the 4 columns where Payer and PPayer columns should be independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `UNION`, you can try like following using `INNER JOIN`.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (
    UserId
    ,DEPT
    ,ROOM
    ,LAB
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ta.UserId
    ,ta.DEPT
    ,ta.ROOM
    ,tb.LAB
FROM TableA ta
INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.UserId = tb.UserId
    AND ta.DEPT = tb.DEPT
```

[Check Working Demo](https://rextester.com/ZFJAJ41226)

Comment: Inner join duplicates the rows, LAB and DEPT then have combinations which it should not have.

Comment: The 3rd table is what the expected output should look like

Comment: Just put DISTINCT, I have updated the answer.

Comment: No, the join does not work even with distinct. The closest I have come is with Union but I cant seem to merge the 2 tables to tables to match the output

Comment: did you checked this https://rextester.com/ZFJAJ41226

Comment: cannot access that link

Answer (score 0):

Shanawaz Khan, Try this Solution

**Declare Sample Table**

```
DECLARE @A as TABLE(
UserId INT,
DEPT VARCHAR(50),
ROOM INT)

DECLARE @B as TABLE(
UserId INT,
DEPT VARCHAR(50),
LAB VARCHAR(50))
```

**Insert Sample Records in Created Table**

```
INSERT INTO @A (UserId,DEPT,ROOM) VALUES(1,'A',1),(1,'B',1),(1,'A',2),(1,'B',2)
INSERT INTO @B (UserId,DEPT,LAB) VALUES(1,'A','P'),(1,'B','Q'),(1,'A','P'),(1,'B','Q')
```

**Generate DEPT wise Row number for Both Tables and Insert into another Temptable**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A.DEPT ORDER BY A.ROOM ) AS Rno,* INTO #tbl_A FROM @A A 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.DEPT ORDER BY B.LAB) AS Rno,* INTO #tbl_B FROM @B B
```

**Final Query Using Inner Join**

```
SELECT  A.UserId,A.DEPT,A.ROOM,B.LAB FROM #tbl_A  AS A
INNER JOIN #tbl_B AS B ON A.Rno =B.Rno AND A.DEPT =B.DEPT ORDER BY A.ROOM, B.DEPT
```

**Drop Created Temptable**

```
DROP TABLE #tbl_A,#tbl_B
```

**OutPut**

[image]

Comment: There are outliers which does not work with this logic. Do you know if we can use union to merge the 2 tables?

Comment: union allows the results of multiple queries to be combined into a single result set and in your case, you want to merge the two different table, So you should use join, instead of the union.